# Safari not decompressing gzip response

Tags: javascript, http, safari, http-headers, gzip

I'm using an API that is responding with gzip encoded data which is working fine in chrome but Safari shows the response as shown below:

[image]

The response headers received are :

```
content-encoding: gzip, gzip 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Chrome is sending a request header **Accept-encoding: gzip deflate** but Safari doesn't.

Can anyone help me fix this please ?

Comment: "content-encoding: gzip, gzip" indicates that the content has been gzipped *twice*. Is this really the case?

Comment: That is an external API, so I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: How about checking?

Comment: Where to check ? All I have is the response headers.

Comment: You do also have the response payload, no?

Comment: The response is null. In the browser inspector the response is as shown as in the image above .

Comment: Please obtain the response payload with a different client such as curl and inspect the actual bytes.